# Algorithm to maximize the smallest diagonal element of a matrix

Tags: algorithm, optimization, matrix, distance, linear-programming

Suppose we are given a square matrix A. Our goal is to maximize the smallest diagonal element by row permutations. In other words, for the given matrix A, we have n diagonal elements and thus we have the minimum $min{d_i}$. Our purpose is to reach the matrix with possibly largest minimum diagonal element by row permutations.

This is like $max min{d_i}$ over all row permutations.

For example, suppose A = [4 3 2 1; 1 4 3 2; 2 1 4 3; 2.5 3.5 4.5 1.5]. The diagonal is [4, 4, 4, 1.5]. The minimum of the diagonal is 1.5. We can swap row 3 and 4 to get to a new matrix \tilde_A = [4 3 2 1; 1 4 3 2; 2.5 3.5 4.5 1.5; 2 1 4 3]. The new diagonal is [4, 4, 4.5, 3] with a new minimum 3. And in theory, this is the best result I can obtain because there seems no better option: 3 seems to be the max min{d_i}.

In my problem, n is much larger like 1000. I know there are n! row permutations so I cannot go through each permutation in theory. I know greedy algorithm will help--we start from the first row. If a_11 is not the smallest in the first column, we swap a_11 with the largest element in the first column by row permutation. Then we look at the second row by comparing a_22 with all remaining elements in the second column(except a_12). Swap a_22 if it is not the smallest. ... ... etc. We keep doing this till the last row.

Is there any better algorithm to do it?

This is similar to Minimum Euclidean Matching but they are not the same.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Could you give an example ? 
As per my current understanding can't you just find the minimum element in the matrix, say a_xy and swap row x with row y ? That will place the minimum element in the matrix at row y, col y

Comment: @user1952500   Thanks a lot for the timely reply. I added an example and hope that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you wanted to know whether there was a better solution to your problem than 3.

Change your matrix to have a 1 for every element that is strictly greater than 3:

```
4    3   2   1     1 0 0 0
1    4   3   2     0 1 0 0
2.5 3.5 4.5 1.5 -> 0 1 1 0
2    1   4   3     0 0 1 0
```

Your problem can be interpreted as trying to find a perfect matching in the bipartite graph which has this binary matrix as its [biadjacency graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix#Adjacency_matrix_of_a_bipartite_graph).

In this case, it is easy to see that there is no way of improving your result because there is no way of reordering rows to make the diagonal entry in the last column greater than 3.

For a larger matrix, there are efficient algorithms to determine [maximal matchings in bipartite graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph#Matching).

This suggests an algorithm:

1. Use bisection to find the largest value for which the generated graph has a perfect matching
2. The assignment corresponding to the perfect matching with the largest value will be equal to the best permutation of rows

### EDIT

This Python code illustrates how to use the [networkx library](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.flow.max_flow.html#networkx.algorithms.flow.max_flow) to determine whether the graph has a perfect matching for a particular cutoff value.

```
import networkx as nx

A = [[4,3,2,1],
     [1,4,3,2],
     [2,1,4,3],
     [2.5,3.5,4.5,1.5]]

cutoff = 3
G=nx.DiGraph()
for i,row in enumerate(A):
    G.add_edge('start','row'+str(i),capacity=1.0)
    G.add_edge('col'+str(i),'end',capacity=1.0)
    for j,e in enumerate(row):
        if e>cutoff:
            G.add_edge('row'+str(i),'col'+str(j),capacity=1.0)

if nx.max_flow(G,'start','end')<len(A):
    print 'No perfect matching'
else:
    print 'Has a perfect matching'
```

For a random matrix of size 1000*1000 it takes about 1 second on my computer.

Comment: Oh my GOD!!! You are a genius!!! I LOVE YOU!!! I will follow your post wherever it goes to. THANKS A LOT!!!

Comment: Could you tell me any fast or good algorithm on how to determine whether the resulting graph I obtain by cuttoff has a perfect matching???

Comment: I've added some example Python code that works in a few seconds for matrices with a million entries.

Comment: @Peter de Rivaz Perfect! You are like a distinguished professor! You replied like a BOSS! I will look into Python now. It seems much smarter and better than MATLAB I'm using now. Just one last question, after I bisect to reach the possible largest cutoff value, how do I find the assignment? Shall I use the max-flow method or the linear programming the other guy mentioned in the question expand? I will try to solve this in MATLAB first though.

Comment: NetworkX can also return you the flow (e.g. this [function](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.flow.ford_fulkerson_flow.html#networkx.algorithms.flow.ford_fulkerson_flow)).  If the flow between row i and col j is 1, that means that row i should be moved to row j.

Comment: @Peter de Rivaz Thank you very much. I already finished most parts. The final problem is how I can connect the assignment with row or column permutations. Suppose I already got the perfect matching (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 4), ... , (40, 38), (1, 39), (2, 40). How do I use these edges when I try to permute the original matrix???

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz   I see. There is a typo in previous post. The matching should be (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 3), ... , (40, 38), (1, 39), (2, 40). For each correspondence, like (3, 1), after I swapped column 3 and column 1, I need change the third edge (5, 3) into (5, 1). This is because every time I make a permutation, the ordering changes accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_{ij}$ be 1 if row i is moved to row j and zero otherwise.

You're interested in the following integer program:

max z

\sum_{i=0}^n x_{ij} = 1 \forall j

\sum_{j=0}^n x_{ij} = 1 \forall i

A[j,j]x_{ij} >= z

Then plug this into GLPK, Gurobi, or CPLEX. Alternatively, solve the IP using your own branch and bound solve.

Comment: Thank you very very much Tom!!! If my matrix is 1K times 1K, does it mean I will have a 1000^2 linear programming problem? Your method should be very useful and I will try it for smaller matrix.

Comment: good point....if you're using open source software, this problem size could definitely be an issue.  however, commercial solvers routinely solve such problems of size 1000^2 and even much larger

Comment: Got it!!! After several hours' reading, I finally understand the meaning of your post. You mean for any cutoff number, I can obtain a corresponding biadjacency matrix. Then I can use your program to find if there exists one or more possible row permutations such that the new diagonal minimum is increased. If the linear program does not have a solution, that means there is no perfect matching for the matrix.

Comment: So can I will try use MATLAB to solve it. That's the only software I know right now. I will touch the three software you mentioned if MATLAB won't work.

Comment: But it is an integer problem, is it #P hard?

Comment: A[j,j]x_{ij} >= z. should it be sumA[j,j]x_{ij} >= z ? And also x_{ij} >= 0.

Comment: I see. You said x_{ij} would be 1 if row i and j are swapped. Does this mean x_{ij} must be equal to x_{ji}, which is 1? Therefore, A_{j,j}x_{ij} should be larger than z for all j's right?

Comment: I will try Ford-Fulkerson algorithm because this is an integer linear programming problem. It should not be an easy one. But I really really appreciate your help bro.

Comment: x_{ij} == x_{ji} would imply you're only considering transpositions (swaps).